# After migrating from Android version 12 to 13, an error by manifest occurs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

targetSdkVersion 32 -> 33

complieSdkVersion 32 -> 33

After migrating from Android version 12 to 13, an error by manifest occurs

```
Starting: Intent { ..... }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {....} does not exist.
```

I found the part where the error occurred.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
                <data
                    android:host="${customUrlScheme}"
                    android:scheme="rsup" />
            </intent-filter>
```

```
<data
                    android:host="${customUrlScheme}"
                    android:scheme="rsup" />
```

If there is this part, the above error occurs If this part is not present, there is no error and it runs. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem at my machine and fixed it by declaring seperate intent-filters like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="${customUrlScheme}"
                android:scheme="rsup" />
        </intent-filter>
```